# Where is name="lc" defined as a meta tag?

Tags: meta-tags, internationalization

I've noticed that ea.com includes a `<meta name="lc" content="en_us"/>` tag on their website which changes for each language/country (`<meta name="lc" content="en_gb"/>`, `<meta name="lc" content="es_mx"/>`, &c).

I can't find any reference to `name="lc"` being a valid meta tag. I've seen `<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en">` and `<html lang="en">`, but where did `name="lc"` come from?

Comment: It looks to me that the person that created the tag is intending it to be "locale".    I do not believe that it is valid.  The [open graph protocol](http://ogp.me/) uses `<meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB" />` which is as close as I could find to something valid and documented.

Comment: To clarify, I'm aware of the purpose of the tag; I'm questioning the validity/origin.

Answer (score 4):

As Stephen said, it is mostly likely an attempt at defining locale. In some of the web-based software that I've worked with, I've come across form values and URLs like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
```

Or

```
page.php?id=233&lc=FRA
```

The meta tag for "lc" is undocumented, which means that it is either a mistake or some sort of custom tag that is used for internal purposes.

Answer (score 3):

It is not valid.

ea.com is using HTML5, but in HTML5 it is only allowed to use `name` values that are

- [defined in the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/document-metadata.html#standard-metadata-names), or
- [registered](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/document-metadata.html#other-metadata-names) on the WHATWG wiki page [MetaExtensions](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions).

`lc` is not included.

If they were using older HTML versions (e.g., HTML 4.01), it [would be valid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16207631/1591669) to use this value.